# Symfony - get User Provider by ID

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jwt

I am using [JWTLexikBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) with [JWTRefreshTokenBundle](https://github.com/gesdinet/JWTRefreshTokenBundle). It was working fine, till I wanted to add more data to token payload (user id to be precise).
It is working fine when logging in, but not throwing errors when refreshing tokens because as i figured out it use diffrent UserProvider and beacuse of that diffrent UserEntity (default one, `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User`). Now, I have my provider configured as follows

```
providers:
    db_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: PrototypeBundle\Entity\User
            property: username
```

Library for JwtRefreshTokens have configuration parmeter for custom UserProvider, but I don't know if or where I can obtain this one declared above.
I think it must be some instance of `@doctrine.orm.security.user.provider` but it is abstract so this dosen't work

```
gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
    firewall: main
    user_provider: '@doctrine.orm.security.user.provider'
```

I tried to found it by doing `bin/console debug:container` but it is nowhere to found there. Is there anyway to get that service Id other than declaring it specificaly and then using that declaration everywhere? If not, how this can done like the most proper way? Using UserRepository with properInterface would be enough?

Comment: I think you will need to define your own user provider service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html I did poke around  bit using debug:container to see if I could find the user provider service id but no luck.  In any event, a custom user provider is easy to implement and will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `'security.user.provider.concrete.'.$name`, in your case - `security.user.provider.concrete.db_user_provider`.

This is generated in `\Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension::getUserProviderId` method.

I don't know if you should really depend on this behavior, as I imagine this could be just an implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks, that do the trick! :D
I will try to play around it to find some nicer solution, but till that it must stay.

Comment: To anyone stumbling here after years as I just did: as I had to also override the base `RefreshToken` entity as I wanted to store `email` instead of `username` as user identifier.